# Measure EMF Radiation from High Altitude Balloon

Tags: emf

I'm participating in a competition which involves building a probe that will be attached to a weather balloon. It will probably rise up to an altitude of 30 km.
I am thinking of measuring EMF radiation with a frequency of ~1GHz. The idea is to determine how much activity there is on the ground (how many cell phones, wifi transmitters etc.). I don't need to extract any information from the signal, I just want to determine the "quantity" of wireless communication.
Due to the nature of the competition I have to deal with the following constraints:

- The sensor may not cost more than 100$
- The weight may not exceed 300 g
- The device must either be small enough to fit into the isolated casing of the probe or be able to withstand temperatures of -40°C

Is it plausible to measure EMF radiation from such a distance? What sort of sensor should I be looking for?

Comment: The only place you can measure EM radiation is at the antenna of your detector. If radio transmissions are reaching that height then you will detect them. If they aren't then you won't. You can't detect radio waves on the ground from high up. Like you can't "see" the photons on the surface of the sun, only the photons that enter your eye and strike the receptors in your retina.

Comment: Post a link to the competition rules because what you have described so far makes no sence especially the Wi-Fi bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chip manufacturers address this kind of sensor with a [good selection of devices.](http://www.analog.com/en/products/rf-microwave/rf-power-detectors/all-rf-power-detectors.html) These provide a voltage output proportional to RF power over a broad range of frequencies - they are not radio receivers because they don't discriminate one signal source from another. Some respond to multiple sources, adding them in a root-mean-square (RMS) fashion, while others don't. Am unsure which is appropriate for your particular application (your specs are not well defined).
Some (many) of these chips are sensitive enough so that an antenna can be attached directly. Your antenna may be a significant challenge, and will influence greatly the frequency band over which signals will add to the output. Your antenna should be carefully designed to be non-directional, since it will likely be spinning and possibly swaying.
Be aware that cell transmitters carefully direct signals in desired directions. Not many users are above a cell site, so less signal is directed "up" than "out and around". But as you go higher, your antenna "sees" more sites.
Engineering is best done to provide a solution to a need. Your need is not mentioned - more like "this might be an interesting thing to measure". Start with a more concrete and useful goal.